# How to design a schema for a site that accepts logins from multiple sites (e.g. facebook connect, google, flickr, etc..)?

Tags: best-practices, schema

I'm building a site (**"The Site"**) and I'm considering how to design the DB schema for it.

I have a few scenarios that will affect the outcome:

- The user can choose to register a native account on **the site**, which will make him use that account for login in to his account on **the site** in the future.
- The user can choose to login via another site (**"external site"**) (such as facebook connect, google, foursquare, etc..), which will make him use that for login in to his account on **the site** in the future.
- Doesn't really matter which login method he chose (native account or external site account), the user will be able to authenticate his account on **the site** with external sites (such as facebook, twitter, instagram, etc...) for using the data he has on the **external site** (such as his tweets from twitter, his photos from flickr, etc..), in **the site**.

How should I design the schema of the DB ?

For the first two scenarios, I thought of having a table called `Users` that has an `id`, and a `type` fields. The type reference a different table, such as `FacebookUsers` or `GoogleUsers`, each has a `user_id` field - which has a foreign relation to the `Users.id` field - and other fields such as the `first_name`, `profile_picture`, etc..

However:

1. I'm not sure how smart it is to use this approach.
2. I don't know how to implement the third scenario in such an approach.

Comment: I'm closing this as off-topic, because this is a website architecture/design/business logic question than a database design question.

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar question in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613867/database-design-for-openid-oauth-twitter-and-facebook)

And the solution is

> You need 2 additional fields in your
>   table, one is the login source
>   (twitter, openID, facebook) and the
>   other is the source user id (the id
>   provided from twitter, openID,
>   facebook) I recommend making this a
>   string as some log in sources have
>   letters in their user IDs and not just
>   numbers. [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613867/database-design-for-openid-oauth-twitter-and-facebook/5613888#5613888)

- I'm not sure how smart it is to use this approach.

> This approach is good, actually sites
>   opting it. see SO login page
>   https://stackoverflow.com/users/login

- I don't know how to implement the third scenario in such an approach.

> I think  you can implement this, only
>   if the thrid party sites provide
>   access. This question is off-topic
>   here, you can ask this in
>   [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)